# Polymerisable Composition - Patent Application - How to challenge novelty

Tags: wo2012160452a1

[WO2012160452A1](http://www.google.com/patents/wo2012160452a1) Two-part polymerisable compositions

A number of parties (including me) will not want this application granted as there are products currently available in the engineering adhesive fields that use 1992 prior art.

For example, BASF has supplied TEB-DAP (C9H25BN2) to my companies for over 7 years. We have also had extensive investigations into its use and its safe sale in EU and worldwide. Nothing in this application appears to be new or novel.  For example, Loctite currently sells a product formerly sold by national Starch under the trade-name V5004 using this TEBDAP.

How does challenge the granting of this application?

Answer (score 1):

At this point it is a PCT application only. The applicants chose the EPO  as the international search authority and the international search report has been issued. The key page of the ISR is below. Three different references are indicated with an "X" as anticipating all claims. It is not likely the application will go very far.

[image]